# Generalize pattern for regular expression with Python3

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract data points from a text file with an example line as seen below:

```
Feb 12 10:49:40 UTC 2020  #  1  #  S0=22.97 S1=28.47 S2=29.12 S3=31.50 S4=32.57 S5=30.03 S6=24.62 S7=28.21 S8=25.41
```

The (very) messy pattern I've come up with is seen below:

```
import re

def parse_data(filename):
pattern = r'.*\s(\d*:\d*:\d*).*S0=(\d*\.\d*)\sS1=(\d*\.\d*)\sS2=(\d*\.\d*)\sS3=(\d*\.\d*)\sS4=(\d*\.\d*)\sS5=(\d*\.\d*)\sS6=(\d*\.\d*)\sS7=(\d*\.\d*)\sS8=(\d*\.\d*).*'
list = []
with open(filename, 'r') as read_file:
    for l in read_file.readlines():
        match = re.match(pattern, l)
    if match:
    s_list = []
    for i in range(2,11):
    s_list.append(match.group(i))
    tuple = (match.group(1), s_list)
    list.append(tuple)
return list
def main():
file1 = 'PythonTest.txt'
list1 = parse_data(file1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

And it works, however if the amount of interesting data points changes I would like to not having to rewrite the pattern specifically for that case. E.g. if I only have a S0 and a S1, or if I have points all the way up to S12. But this is beyond my skill, is it possible to write a more generalized pattern? And if so, how will they be indexed in groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern depending on your needs:

```py
import re

txt = """
S0=22.97 S1=28.47 S2=29.12 S3=31.50 S4=32.57 S5=30.03 S6=24.62 S7=28.21 S8=25.41 
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'(S\d+)=(\d+\.\d+)')
for match in pattern.finditer(txt):
    print(match.group(1), '=' ,match.group(2))

>>> S0 = 22.97
>>> S1 = 28.47
>>> S2 = 29.12
>>> S3 = 31.50
>>> S4 = 32.57
>>> S5 = 30.03
>>> S6 = 24.62
>>> S7 = 28.21
>>> S8 = 25.41
```